# IDE para django?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Boa noite galera, estou tendo grandes problemas com algumas ides, precisando de um conselho de vocês. Tô tentando programar projetos web em python, para isso instalei o pycharm para trabalhar... A principio é uma ótima IDE, mas parece que o mundo nem faz uso. O mais engraçado é que estou tentando fazer o bendito "hello world" em django, no pycharm, mas só dou de cara com tracebacks, mesmo usando uma virtualenv em python 3 como interpretador. 
Logo pergunto aos camaradas, vale a pena insistir? Embora seja muito pratica, essa dor de cabeça por tão pouco é valida?
Fico no aguardo.

Olha ai o meu atual problema no pycharm:

```
/home/user/mv_python/django/bin/python 
/home/user/PycharmProjects/django_ecommerce/manage.py runserver 
8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in 
Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put 
the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: 
TEMPLATE_DIRS.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly 
until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, 
sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
August 16, 2017 - 20:16:37
Django version 1.11.4, using settings 'django_ecommerce.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/mv_python/django/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/user/mv_python/django/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/user/mv_python/django/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)
File 
"/home/user/PycharmProjects/django_ecommerce/core/views.py", 
line 7, in index
return render(request, 'index.html ')
File "/home/user/mv_python/django/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, 
using=using)
File "/home/user/mv_python/django/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/loader.py", line 67, in render_to_string
template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
File "/home/user/mv_python/django/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/django/template/loader.py", line 25, in get_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html 
[16/Aug/2017 20:16:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 83461
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[16/Aug/2017 20:16:40] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2074
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[16/Aug/2017 20:16:40] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2074

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: O problema não tem nada a ver com o pycharm, sem medo de errar posso lhe afirmar que pycharm está entre as melhores ide's no mundo python e é usada por 99,99% dos desenvolvedores experientes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Também encontrei uma solução para o erro

```
WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in 
Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put 
the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: 
TEMPLATE_DIRS
```

No [stack em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445953/django-app-works-fine-but-getting-a-template-warning-message)

> Defina **debug** no dicionário **OPTIONS** das configurações dos seus
>   modelos.

```
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]
```

Em seguida, remova esta linha das suas configurações para interromper as advertências

```
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

> Também na linha **7** do arquivo **views.py**, contem um espaço no
>   final

```
File 
"/home/user/PycharmProjects/django_ecommerce/core/views.py", 
line 7, in index
return render(request, 'index.html ')
```

> Verifica se o arquivo **index.html** existe, caso contrário não
>   ira funcionar mesmo.

Comment: Vlw Wellinghton, sim o arquivo index.html existe eu tinha criado porém não conseguia chama-lo. Acabei criando a pasta template, que o pycharm cria para dentro da pasta "core" que é minha aplicação, mas não está conseguindo chamar.... Passei horas tentando debugar, mas sem entender qual era o erro afinal! Vou modificar e depois retorno!